# Java getHostName error?

Tags: java, dns

I have a problem using the 
`InetAdress.getHostName()` class in java. In some cases the java class did not get a correct result. In this cases I receive (as expected at an error) just the IP address.

Most likely this is an error in the dns configuration of our network. But if I use the command line with `nslookup`, I receive the right answer.

Does java use a different DNS config than the rest of the system? Can anyone explain how this might happen? 
Is there an alternative for `getHostName()`?

Comment: have a look at "getCanonicalHostName()"
see also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName() edit:// when I remember correct gethostname returns only hostnames which are allready known by the machine?

Comment: The behavior of get canonical host name is not different for me. Ether way I receive only the IP address.

Comment: may try an nslookup with this ip adress and try a gethostname again. report your result please

Comment: Tried several times, no difference. I can resolve 90 of 100 unknown hosts without a problem. Just the rest is generating this strange behavior.

Comment: Have the same issue on java8/openjdk/linux. Did you found any answers or workarounds to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[getHostName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29)

> Gets the host name for this IP address.

[getCanonicalHostName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName%28%29)

> Gets the fully qualified domain name for this IP address

Comment: For me there is no difference between those. I receive only the IP address.

Comment: how are you creating the `InetAdress`?

Comment: I am using  getByName("11.22.33.44");

Comment: what OS are you running it on?

Comment: Win 7 SP 1 Java version 1.7.0_17 I have seen the java error report for OSX and ubuntu

Comment: is `InetAdress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()` also returning an ip adress?

Comment: Yes, as well as  most of my other tested IP addresses. There are just a few generating this error.

Comment: could you try running it as _admin_?

Comment: Sorry: asking local host I get the correct F QDN of my computer. Not the IP address. I do not have admin rights on this machine

Comment: `getByName` will return you an InetAdress even when this ip does not exists

Comment: Thanks for your help. My IP is correct I can ping the adress , and I can resolve it using nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

I see it is a quite old question but today I ran into the same problem and looks like I found a reason.
The problem is, that java (at least openjdk version "1.8.0_121") lookin up the "PTR" record first, and then, if any results were found, java tries to perform an "A" record lookup, comparing returned "A" records with the initial IP number queried. And if no such IPs were found for an "A" query, Java won't return the "PTR" lookup result. They call it "prevent spoofing". Here's the library sources:

```
private static String getHostFromNameService(InetAddress addr, boolean check) {
String host = null;
for (NameService nameService : nameServices) {
    try {
        // first lookup the hostname
        host = nameService.getHostByAddr(addr.getAddress());

        /* check to see if calling code is allowed to know
         * the hostname for this IP address, ie, connect to the host
         */
        if (check) {
            SecurityManager sec = System.getSecurityManager();
            if (sec != null) {
                sec.checkConnect(host, -1);
            }
        }

        /* now get all the IP addresses for this hostname,
         * and make sure one of them matches the original IP
         * address. We do this to try and prevent spoofing.
         */

        InetAddress[] arr = InetAddress.getAllByName0(host, check);
        boolean ok = false;

        if(arr != null) {
            for(int i = 0; !ok && i < arr.length; i++) {
                ok = addr.equals(arr[i]);
            }
        }

        //XXX: if it looks a spoof just return the address?
        if (!ok) {
            host = addr.getHostAddress();
            return host;
        }

        break;
```

What could I say? Omitting naughty words - nothing.
Since this lib is shared from the Oracle JRE, there's nothing else we could do.